# Hibernate putting backticks around columnDefinition

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a column in the database which has been defined as follows in the entity class:

```
@Column(name="lastlogindate", columnDefinition ="TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP")
private Timestamp lastlogindate;
```

The `create table` command that is being generated is as follows:

```
create table usermaster (
  lastlogindate `TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`)
```

while what works is

```
create table usermaster (
  lastlogindate TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
```

Hibernate reports the following error while creating tables:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`,

Unable to understand why extra ticks are being added and how to avoid it.

The version details are as follows:

- HIBERNATE VERSION: 4.3.8.Final
- MySQL version:5.6.26
- MySQL Dialect information:

```xml
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="transaction.factory_class">
    org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransactionFactory</property>
    <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit ">false</property>
    <property name="hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers">true</property>
```

Comment: I can't find those extra characters.

Comment: I see. We will need your: MySQL datasource config (especially if there is any dialect configured); Exact Hibernate version; MySQL version.

Comment: Have updated the information asked in the problem description.

Answer (score 2):

Please remove the following config line:

```
<property name="hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers">true</property>
```

This is likely not needed and almost surely causing the problem you experience.

**UPDATE:**

The issue was finally solved by changing the dialect to MySQL5 from generic MySQL:

```
org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

Comment: Still facing the same problem...extra backticks in columnDefinition

Comment: Could you try to adjust your dialect setting? The one you are using is a generic MySQL. Here is a full list of dialects available, including MySQL5 and specific version for InnoDB / ISAM: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#configuration-optional-dialects

Comment: It worked after changing the dialect to org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect.Thanks for the help.

Comment: Good to hear. I am still surprised a bit, but at least the issue is gone.