# Error on SQL generated by Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

Does anybody know why the SQL query generated by Hibernate is wrong? I tried to create a table from entity automatically using property `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` = `create-drop` with `columnDefinition` in the entity to set the default value. When I run the program I got this error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; 
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version 
for the right syntax to use near '`varchar(100) default '-'`, 
`last_name` varchar(100), primary key (`id'
```

Here is the generated SQL query:

```
create table `user` (
    `id` bigint not null auto_increment, 
    `first_name` `varchar(100) default '-'`,
    `last_name` varchar(64), 
    primary key (`system_id`)
)
```

Of course that was wrong, Hibernate add a tick character (`) for translating `columnDefinition` in the entity, here is the entity class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = UserEntity.TABLE_NAME)
public class UserEntity implements Serializable {

    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "user";

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "first_name", columnDefinition="varchar(100) default '-'")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name", length = 100)
    private String lastName;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

}
```

Depedencies in maven:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.30</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.10.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.10.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

Please let me know if somebody get the same problem and get the solution. Thank you for your help.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34991684/hibernate-putting-backticks-around-columndefinition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link on the comment, helped me. The problem is in my hibernate configuration, removing this line fix it.

```
<property name="hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers">true</property>
```